# Unable to generate deps.json to enable migrations

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I use Asp.net core mvc for web developing.
I want to enable entityframework migrations via Entity Framework Core .NET Command Line Tools:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialDatabase
```

but an error occurs:
**unable to generate deps.json, it may have been already generated: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\GenerateDeps\GenerateDeps.proj**

Are there any .NET Core configs that I missed?

Comment: Try running `dotnet restore` first.

Answer (score 0):

When I add a service reference to a regular.net core web application, I got the similar error.

> Error:Unable to generate deps.json, it may have been already
>   generated.  You can specify the "-d" option before the tool name for
>   diagnostic output (for example, "dotnet -d ": C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.502\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\GenerateDeps\GenerateDeps.proj

After the investigation I came to know that, somehow svcutil was not installed. Once I installed svcutil using Nuget Package Manager (`Install-Package dotnet-svcutil`), this issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install :

> The Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) [dotnet-svcutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x) tool is a
>   .NET Core CLI tool that retrieves metadata from a web service on a
>   network location or from a WSDL file, and generates a WCF class
>   containing client proxy methods that access the web service
>   operations.

```
> Install-Package dotnet-svcutil -Version 1.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

My project was using dotnet core 2.2. I had to use dotnet-svcutil 1.0.4 because higher versions did not work for me.
Installing dotnet-svcutil did the trick for me. You can search for dotnet-svcutil under "Manage Packages for solution" from Nuget Packages Manager under tools and then install